# How to move the edit tab in user-profile.tpl.php

Tags: 7, theming

I would want to reorganize the profile of the users, in the following way:

1. Name (h1),
2. Custom field 1,
3. Custom field 2,
4. Edit tab ($tab),
5. Block.

I tried to delete the $tab variable in page--user.tpl.php, and add it in user--profile.tpl.php, but it does not work.

How to move the edit tab in user-profile.tpl.php ?

Comment: Just to make sure that it's a typo in your question: you should use `user-profile.tpl.php` (one dash, see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user-profile.tpl.php/7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i find the answer :

```
function THEME_preprocess_user_profile(&$variables) {
  $variables['tabs'] = menu_local_tabs();
}
```